# Maximizing the sum of the lengths of a walk in a directed acyclic graph (DAG)

Tags: graph-theory

You are given $V$ vertices and $E$ edges.

Define a walk rooted in $s$ to mean a path obtained by starting from $s$ and following edges until you reach a node pointing to no other edges (this must exist in a DAG)

How should you construct a graph to maximize the sum of the lengths of the unique walks starting from $s$?

---

My idea  was to have a structure like this:

You have the edge $(s, w_1)$ and then edges $(s, v_1), (v_1, w_1); (s, v_2), (v_2, w_1); \dots; (s, v_m), (v_m, w_1)$ and the edges $(w_1, w_2), (w_2, w_3), \dots, (w_{n-1}, w_n)$.

This way the walks are $s \to w_1 \to w_2 \to \dots \to w_n$ (length $n$, $1$ such walk) or $s \to v_k \to w_1 \to w_2 \to \dots \to w_n$ (length $n+1$, $m$ such walks)

And then maximizing this sum $n + m(n+1)$ under the constraint that $n + m = E$.

I'm not really sure how to approach this problem in a formal way.

Comment: It seems that you have constraints $n+m=V$ and $2m+n-1=E$ for your structure.